# How to record bad lines skipped by pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

I'm reading a CSV file with pandas with

```
error_bad_lines=False
```

A warning is printed when a bad line is encountered. However, I want to keep a record of all the bad line numbers to feed into another program. Is there an easy way of doing that?

I thought about iterating over the file with a

```
chunksize=1
```

and catching the CParserError that ought to be thrown for each bad line encountered. When I do this though no CParserError is thrown for bad lines so I can't catch them.

Answer (score 10):

Warnings are printed in the standard error channel.  You can capture them to a file by redirecting the `sys.stderr` output.

```
import sys
import pandas as pd

with open('bad_lines.txt', 'w') as fp:
    sys.stderr = fp
    pd.read_csv('my_data.csv', error_bad_lines=False)
```

Comment: I tried this out without any success. I don't think these are actually warnings but rather text printed to console. Any insights?

Comment: That's odd, this definitely works for me on my Windows system.  It looks like printed text; but it can be captured through the `sys.stderr` stream, at least on Windows.

Comment: Lines 2600-2602 of the pandas/parsers.py is where the output line produced. `base = 'Skipping line {row_num}: '.format(row_num=row_num)`
and `sys.stderr.write(base + msg + '\n')`.  So it is definitely writing to `sys.stderr`.  See the file here:  https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/f6f5ce5f9ce2afc3b6f55a3228b93024b121b88f/pandas/io/parsers.py

Comment: Thank you, @James. For some reason, I'm struggling to find the same set of lines in version 19. I guess it's time to update. In the meantime, I found a workaround redirecting `sys.stdout`. It's not pretty, though, so the upgrade is a better solution.