# numpy genfromtext or numpy loadtxt " ValueError: could not convert string to float" or "too many values to unpack", tried almost everything

Tags: python, csv, numpy

I have a very frustrating problem trying to solve for many hours now. I really maxed out all topics here on google with relevant questions and answers.

What I would like to do:
I have big datasets (50-70k columns in CSV) of photometry data that I would like to load in, then work with them as floats and plot them eventually with some fittings and calculations.

an example of the data:

```
Time(s),AnalogIn-1,AnalogIn-2
0.00E+00,3.96E-02,3.33E-02
0.00E+00,4.10E-02,3.33E-02
```

So each column has many numbers with scientific notation.

In my code I first used the following to load the text:

```
time, dat1, dat2= np.loadtxt(path, skiprows=1, unpack=True, delimiter=",")
```

And it's been dropping "ValueError: could not convert string to float:"

It works fine if I go to for e.g Excel, convert the whole CSV sheet from 'General' to 'Numbers.

I tried literally everything discussed here, first starting with skipping headers and first rows, both with `np.loadtxt`, `np.genfromtxt` or with pandas loader. Also tried to change datatypes, fixing converters, re-mapping whatever what was loaded to floats. This helped, but only for certain rows and error popped in soon at random rows or popped back 'Too many values to unpack'. - I tried skip blank, nan also. I suspect the problem still somewhere in the conversion, that the scientific notation is indeed a string and it has "E" "+" and "-" chars in "random" order. I still believe I'm missing something very easy solution to this, as my CSV is really standard data.

Comment: Why are you saying `delimiter=","` when your data is delimited by spaces?

Comment: Those commas for decimal separators are going to be a problem, though.

Comment: Thanks for noticing! I just corrected the post, bad formatting. it is indeed "," delimited and decimal separators are dots.

Comment: There are no commas in your edited data. Why do you say it's comma-delimited?

Comment: can you provide a link to the csv?

Comment: When trying to get the reader working, skip the `unpack` stuff.  That just complicates life.  Let it return a single array, which you can examine for shape and dtype.

Comment: if you can stomach loosing some of the data, you might consider using the `error_bad_lines=False` flag in `pd.read_csv` method.  If not, you might have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42856255/how-to-record-bad-lines-skipped-by-pandas) to find out which lines in the file are causing the error.

Comment: Thanks all. dubbbdan please find csv here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1batwyi8u2sUdKwWkqHLL2QpO5kO8dwUK

I have tried it without unpack, still no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really just a long comment, but if it identifies the problem, it might be an answer.

With the CSV file that you linked to in a comment, I ran

```
time, dat1, dat2 = np.loadtxt("data1.csv", skiprows=1, unpack=True, delimiter=",")
```

and it worked with no errors.

When I inspected the file, I noticed that the line endings were a single carriage return character (often abbreviated CR, hex code `0d`).  You mentioned using Excel, so I assume you are using Windows.  The usual line ending in Windows is CR+LF (two characters: carriage return followed by linefeed; hex `0d0a`).

That might be the problem (but I expected Python file I/O to take care of this).  I don't have a Windows system to test this, so at the moment all I can say is "try this":

```
with open('data1.csv', 'r', newline='\r') as f:
    time, dat1, dat2 = np.loadtxt(f, skiprows=1, unpack=True, delimiter=",")
```

Comment: Thank you Warren! This actually worked together with specifying usecols[0,1,2]. And yes, it is on a Windows PC

Answer (score 1):

With your sample `loadtxt` works fine:

```
In [142]: np.loadtxt(txt.splitlines(), delimiter=',',skiprows=1)
Out[142]: 
array([[ 0.    ,  0.0396,  0.0333],
       [ 0.    ,  0.041 ,  0.0333]])
In [143]: time,dat1,dat2=np.loadtxt(txt.splitlines(), delimiter=',',skiprows=1,
     ...: unpack=True)
In [144]: time,dat1,dat2
Out[144]: (array([ 0.,  0.]), array([ 0.0396,  0.041 ]), array([ 0.0333,  0.0333]))
```

Now if I change one of the txt lines to:

```
0.00E+00,3.96E-02,3.33E+-02
```

I get an error like yours:

```
In [146]: np.loadtxt(txt.splitlines(), delimiter=',',skiprows=1)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-146-ff3d27e104fc> in <module>()
----> 1 np.loadtxt(txt.splitlines(), delimiter=',',skiprows=1)

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py in loadtxt(fname, dtype, comments, delimiter, converters, skiprows, usecols, unpack, ndmin)
   1022 
   1023             # Convert each value according to its column and store
-> 1024             items = [conv(val) for (conv, val) in zip(converters, vals)]
   1025             # Then pack it according to the dtype's nesting
   1026             items = pack_items(items, packing)

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py in <listcomp>(.0)
   1022 
   1023             # Convert each value according to its column and store
-> 1024             items = [conv(val) for (conv, val) in zip(converters, vals)]
   1025             # Then pack it according to the dtype's nesting
   1026             items = pack_items(items, packing)

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py in floatconv(x)
    723         if b'0x' in x:
    724             return float.fromhex(asstr(x))
--> 725         return float(x)
    726 
    727     typ = dtype.type

ValueError: could not convert string to float: b'3.33E+-02
```

Notice that my error shows the problem string.  Does your's do that as well?  If so, why didn't you include that information?  Also you don't include any of the traceback.  We don't need to see it in all its glory, but some helps when setting context.

I tried the `+-` because I vaguely recall some SO questions along that line, either a Python formatter producing that kind of exponential, or have problems reading that.  We could search for details if needed.

If the load works for some lines, but fails on others, you need to isolate the problem lines, and test them.

---

Downloading your link, I have no problem loading the file:

```
In [147]: np.loadtxt('/home/paul/Downloads/data1.csv', delimiter=',',skiprows=1)
Out[147]: 
array([[  0.00000000e+00,   3.96000000e-02,   3.33000000e-02],
       [  0.00000000e+00,   4.10000000e-02,   3.33000000e-02],
       [  6.94000000e-04,   4.10000000e-02,   3.40000000e-02],
       ..., 
       [  8.02000000e+00,   3.96000000e-02,   3.19000000e-02],
       [  8.02000000e+00,   3.82000000e-02,   3.33000000e-02],
       [  8.02000000e+00,   3.75000000e-02,   3.33000000e-02]])
In [148]: data = _
In [149]: data.shape
Out[149]: (71600, 3)
```

---

'Too many values to unpack' - I don't like to use `unpack` unless I know for sure the number of columns in the file (not probably not even then).

```
In [169]: a1,a2 = np.loadtxt(txt.splitlines(), delimiter=',',skiprows=1,unpack=
     ...: True)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-169-4dea7c2876c1> in <module>()
----> 1 a1,a2 = np.loadtxt(txt.splitlines(), delimiter=',',skiprows=1,unpack=True)

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Again the full error message - you left off the `expected`.  The file sample produces 3 columns, so I get this error if I provide the wrong number of variables.

With `unpack` it may be wise to specify the number of columns, eg

```
In [170]: a1,a2 = np.loadtxt(txt.splitlines(), delimiter=',',skiprows=1,unpack=
     ...: True, usecols=[1,2])
```