# np.genfromtxt returns one dimensional array with mulitiple nan's

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, csv, numpy

I'm following a youtube lecture on NumPy. The lecturer created a .csv file(in Excel) and saved it as lookatarray.csv, this file contains the following data

```
0.00E+00    1.00E+00    2.00E+00    3.00E+00
0.00E+00    1.00E+00    2.00E+00    3.00E+00
0.00E+00    1.00E+00    2.00E+00
```

While trying to retrieve it with

```
r = np.genfromtxt('lookatarray.csv', delimiter = ',')
```

I have got the following output:

```
[  0.   1.   2.  nan   1.   2.  nan   1.   2.  nan]
```

What is going on here?

Comment: You used `delimiter = ','`.  Is the data in the file actually delimited by commas?  Your sample doesn't show them.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser: No, the data in the file isn't delimited by commas.

Comment: OK, then don't use `delimiter=','`.  By default, `genfromtxt` assumes that the fields are separated by whitespace.  If that is the case for your file, you can simply remove the `delimiter` argument.  You'll still have a problem with that last line.  `genfromtxt` assumes that all lines have the same number of columns, so you'll get an error when it tries to read that line.  You can use the argument `invalid_raise=False`, but then it will simply *ignore* the short line.

Comment: The resultant of 'np.genfromtxt('lookatarray.csv', invalid_raise=False)' is '[ nan  nan  nan]'

Comment: *"I have got the following output: [...]"*  I copied your data into a file, and I haven't found any way to get `genfromtxt` to return the result that you show here.  Is the sample that you show an exact representation of what is in the file?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser: Yes, after double checking.

Comment: Hold on, this looks familiar.  You could get `[  0.   1.   2.  nan   1.   2.  nan   1.   2.  nan]` if `genfromtxt` wasn't interpreting the line ending correctly.  Check out this answer to another question about reading a text file created with Excel: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47559510/numpy-genfromtext-or-numpy-loadtxt-valueerror-could-not-convert-string-to-flo/47561983#47561983

Comment: Please edit the question to show the contents of the file `lookatarray.csv`.  As you noted in a comment to an answer that I deleted, the CSV file does, in fact, use commas as the field delimiter.